# I fixed my dilemma with the looping issue. But How can I make it so I dont have to press R? As in, any other key pressed will loop?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

import java.util.Scanner;

public class CurrencyConversion{

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    // declare and initialize variables
    double dollars = 0;
    //double euro = 0;
    // declare scanner
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int loopVal = 0;
    boolean loop = true;
    while( loopVal < 1 && loop == true){
        //Prompt user for dollar amount
    System.out.print("Enter the dollar amount $");
    dollars = scan.nextDouble();
    loopVal ++;
    loop = false;
        while( loopVal == 1 && loop == false){

            System.out.print("Press Q to quit,or R to resume");
            String input = scan.nextLine();
            if( input.equalsIgnoreCase("Q")){
                break;
            } // end if one

            if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("R"))
            {

                loop = true;
                loopVal = 0;


            }// end else

        } // end second while


    } // end first while





}// end main method
```

}// end class

Comment: Unrelated to the problem at hand, when dealing with money you generally want to avoid using doubles. They are an approximation of the number and can result in incorrect values. So have a look at using BigDecimal or even int in place of the doubles. 

Also, have a look at using Break; to exit out of a loop early.

Answer (score 4):

First, your code is case sensitive - "Q" would work but 'q' would not.  You should use input.equalsIgnoreCase("Q") to avoid this.

Second, you're not doing anything when "input == Q" - perhaps you want to simply use break to escape your while loop in that case?  Be careful without {}'s around your if...only the first line after the if is executed if you don't wrap that in {}'s.

I think you want something like this:

```
       while( loopVal == 1 && loop == false){
            System.out.print("Press Q to quit, any other key to resume ");
            String input = scan.nextLine();
            if ( input.equalsIgnoreCase("Q")) 
            { 
               loop = false; 
            }
            else {
               // whatever else
            }

        }
```

Comment: while( loopVal < 1 && loop == true){
   //Prompt user for dollar amount
  System.out.print("Enter the dollar amount $");
  dollars = scan.nextDouble();
  loopVal ++;
  loop = false;
   while( loopVal == 1 && loop == false){
    
    System.out.print("Press Q to quit, any other key to resume ");
    String input = scan.nextLine();
    if ( input.equalsIgnoreCase("Q")){
     loop = false;
    }// end first if
    else {
     loop = true;
     loopVal = 0;
     
    }// end else

Comment: Jarone - not sure what your comment was asking - do you have further issues/questions?

Comment: Sorry, thanks for the help!!! I have updated my program above and  I was curious on how to use a code where I dont have to press "R" to return back to the loop. I was interested in pressing any key besides "Q" that would return back to the loop. I tried to use else { loop = true; loopVal = 0} // but this doesnt work

Comment: Don't set your loop control variable to false before entering the loop.  Only set it in the "Q" case.  Also, why do you have both a "loop" flag and a "loopval" - I suggest simplifying things and just having a single variable control whether or not your loop runs.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I will fiddle with things and hopefully everything works out.

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't understand  `input != "Q"` , remember that String is a class in Java.

rather - use `public boolean equalsIgnoreCase` or similar.

See this - http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29

Also here, Compare strings example - http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/CompString.shtml

Comment: Oh okay, let me fiddle with it.